# How to change html text to normal text parse in texteditingcontroller() to edit in textformfield

Tags: html, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I want to remove html tags or format html text to normal text and also tried to added html package that helps to parsing text widget and it working for display text but when parsing texteditingcontroller()'
to edit text in textformfield' but html text in between edit text
it doesn't work for that i tried htmleditorenhanced'
Package it returns missingpluginexception' and hanging issue

And to remove html tags, i tried with htmlparser' it is not proper text

Any other way to change html string to normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with package:html you can get text of document nodes

```
import 'package:html/parser.dart' show parse;
import 'package:html/dom.dart';

var document = parse(html);
for(var child in document.children){
  for(var node in child.children){
   print(node.text);
  }
}
```